# why tablet with Android 2.3.3 7 inch it's using resources to smartphones?

Tags: android

I have developed an android app to run as smartphones as tablets, I'm aiming the compability between 2.3 to 4.2, so 
I've created the layout folders: layout to smartphones, layout-sw600dp and layout-sw720 to tablets and drawble-ldpi, drawble-mdpi, drawble-hdpi, 
drawble-large and drawble-xlarge to images. Now my boss gave me a tablet with Android 2.3.3 GINGERBREAD and 7 inch, this device allow 
to make phone call, but this device isn't only a phone it is a tablet with 7 inch, however when I install the app in this tablet, 
it is using the layouts from layout folder, I dont know the reason, instead of using the proper layout folder and drawble-sw600 it is using resource 
that should be used only by smarphones, Anyone knows tell me how to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: just check when sw600dp  was added (which API lvl)

Comment: What brand is this Tablet?  I know the first version of the Samsung Galaxy Tab 7 did some funny stuff with the display that might mean it is recognized as a phone.  Also you might want to output some of the display metrics to see what the tablet is reporting to the os.  It might be dropping into the lower than 600dp bucket because of how it is reporting.

Comment: @Selvin has it right.  You might consider using layout-large instead of the density specific folder

Comment: Good point Selvin.  I just checked for user and it was added in 3.2.  That's probably their problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a folder layout-large for pre-3.2 Android devices.

http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html